# Module scope and variable garbage collection in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm reviewing some code that exports a function from a Node.js module. The code looks like this

```
const { getClient } = require('...');

let authClient;

function getAuthClient() {
  if (!authClient) {
      authClient = getClient();
    }
  return client;
}

module.exports = getAuthClient;
```

From what I understand, in Node.js, variables that are not explicitly exported will only be scoped to the module/file. So it seems to me that the `authClient` variable will be garbage collected once this exported functions runs once. The object it refers to will not be garbage collected, however.

As I currently see it, declaring the authClient variable outside of the function's scope seems pointless. Won't it ALWAYS be undefined and thus the `if (!authClient)` will always run, replacing the existing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAuthClient` is exported and it still holds a reference to the `authClient` variable because it uses it so it is not garbage collected.

Comment: Also I know from experience that you can define "global" module scoped variables and use them in functions without exporting them. I use this pattern on a regular basis.